# Border color change like a progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to add border effect that changes color partially when scrolled down. My problem is that this code changes the color of the borders completely and all of them at once. What it needs to do is, changing the color of the individual border partially while scrolling down the page. Just like a progress bar. My code is also problem i know but i'm not good at Jquery. Help me out on this please.

Thanks

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 40 && scroll < 80) {
    jQuery(".wpb_text_column").removeClass("green");
    jQuery(".wpb_text_column").addClass("blue");
  } else if (scroll >= 80) {
    jQuery(".wpb_text_column").removeClass("blue");
    jQuery(".wpb_text_column").addClass("green");
  } else {
    jQuery(".wpb_text_column").removeClass("blue", "green");
  }
});
```

```css
.wpb_text_column {
  border-left: 5px solid #2451ae!important;
  transition: border-left-color 0.9s ease;
}

.blue {
  border-left: 5px solid blue!important;
  transition: border-left-color 0.9s ease;
}

.green {
  border-left: 5px solid green!important;
  transition: border-left-color 1s ease;
}

.wpb_text_column .wpb_wrapper {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

body {
  min-height: 800px;
  transition: background-color 0.75s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_text_column">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et</p>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="wpb_text_column">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et</p>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="wpb_text_column">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et</p>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="wpb_text_column">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but what's the problem?

Comment: What about a CSS (color) transition?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina the color of the borders doesn't change partially like a progress bar. Instead it changes all the borders at once.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I have added the transition ruler in CSS. One of them is and it also has color ruler > 
.green {
  border-left: 5px solid green!important;
}

Comment: Do you mean that you want part of the border to remain the original color and this part shrink the more the user scrolls?

Comment: @AHaworth while you scrolling down, the bars (borders) should change colors one by one and even then they need to do it in a smooth way like from top to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking the scroll length for the window and setting all of the bars based off of that, so that when the window passes 40px in scrolling *all* the bars change color. What you want to do is set up a `for` loop so that when the window scrolls, it checks *each bar* individually for the distance from the top.

Try this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  for (let bar of jQuery('.wpb_text_column')) {
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop() - jQuery(bar).offset().top;

    if (scroll < -40) {
      jQuery(bar).removeClass("green");
      jQuery(bar).addClass("blue");
    } else if (scroll >= -40) {
      jQuery(bar).removeClass("blue");
      jQuery(bar).addClass("green");
    } else {
      jQuery(bar).removeClass("blue", "green");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I was working sorry for late answer. I have tried the solution made some customization and it works just the way i want it. Thanks.